# How can I resolve "Not all control paths return a value" error for integer

Tags: mql4, algorithmic-trading, metatrader4, mt4

I have the error "Not all control paths return a value". I've seen it before and have been able to resolve it for a simple bool return value. This is a bit different and  seems to be a challenge for me since it has a for-loop and at the same time returns integers. Please see my code below:

```
int ArrowedCandleIndex  () {

      for (int i=0; i<NumBars; i++)
      {
         double dnArrow = iCustom(Symbol(),Period(),ARROWS_SIGNAL_NAME,ARROWS_SIGNAL_BUFFER_DN,i);
         double upArrow = iCustom(Symbol(),Period(),ARROWS_SIGNAL_NAME,ARROWS_SIGNAL_BUFFER_UP,i);

         if ((dnArrow!=EMPTY_VALUE) && (DoubleToStr(dnArrow,Digits()) != "0.00000"))  {

            currentArrowedCandleIndex = NumBars;

            return currentArrowedCandleIndex;
            }
         if ((upArrow!=EMPTY_VALUE) && (DoubleToStr(upArrow,Digits()) != "0.00000"))  {
            currentArrowedCandleIndex = NumBars;

            return currentArrowedCandleIndex;
            }
      }
  }
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: What happens if you make it all the way to the end of the `for` loop without finding anything?

Comment: @RaymondChen it should return -1

Comment: If hat's what it should do, then you should do that.

Answer (score 1):

> **Q** : "*How can I resolve this  <sub>(  "Not all control paths return a value" )</sub> issue?*"

```
int ArrowedCandleIndex  () {

      for ( int i = 0; i <  NumBars; i++ )
      {
         ...    
         if (  (  EMPTY_VALUE != dnArrow )
            && ( "0.00000"    != DoubleToStr( dnArrow, Digits() ) )
               ) {
                 ...
                 return currentArrowedCandleIndex; // ------------ JIT/RET--(a)
         }

         if (  (  EMPTY_VALUE != upArrow )
            && ( "0.00000"    != DoubleToStr( upArrow, Digits() ) )
               ) {
                 ...
                 return currentArrowedCandleIndex; // ------------ JIT/RET--(b)
            }
      }
      return EMPTY_VALUE; // ------------------------------------- JIT/RET--(c)
  }
```